# Easier way to show link from dropdown using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

This is my first attempt at JQuery, I am building a world clock using an embedded iframe from http://www.timeanddate.com - the concept is the user selects the city from the dropdown and it will show the correct time for that city

```
<div>
        <select>
<option value="n136" selected>London</option>
<option value="n240">Sydney</option>
<option value="n179">New York City</option>
        </select>
</div>
<div class ="n136 time"><iframe src="https://freesecure.timeanddate.com/clock/i50ppgou/n136/tluk/fcf90/tct/pct/ftb/bo2/pa10/th1" frameborder="0" width="80" height="38" allowTransparency="true"></iframe></div>
<div class ="n240 time"><iframe src="https://freesecure.timeanddate.com/clock/i50ppgou/n240/tluk/fcf90/tct/pct/ftb/bo2/pa10/th1" frameborder="0" width="80" height="38" allowTransparency="true"></iframe></div>
<div class ="n179 time"><iframe src="https://freesecure.timeanddate.com/clock/i50ppgou/n179/tluk/fcf90/tct/pct/ftb/bo2/pa10/th1" frameborder="0" width="80" height="38" allowTransparency="true"></iframe></div>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").change(function() {
    $(this).find("option:selected").each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr("value") == "n136") {
        $(".time").not(".n136").hide();
        $(".n136").show();
      } else if ($(this).attr("value") == "n240") {
        $(".time").not(".n240").hide();
        $(".n240").show();
      } else if ($(this).attr("value") == "n179") {
        $(".time").not(".n179").hide();
        $(".n179").show();
      } else {
        $(".time").hide();
      }
    });
  }).change();
});
```

It works.
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/p8ARq/609/)

The problem is I have 10 more world times to add in, this will become a really large script and will load 13 world times, hiding 12, this seems really bad practice, I think it could be vastly improved if only one IFrame is loaded, then when the user selects a city from the dropdown the value change part of the URL of the Iframe (as if the n*** number is a variable) to the div class as each of them are the correct codes for each city. That would be much more efficent.

[image]

However I seem to have hit my limit with JQuery, if anyone could help out or even get me started it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried simply setting the `src` attribute of the `iframe`, your problem with needing a different code in the url could be resolved using replace in a string.format pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the keyword `this` in your selector and change the src of one iframe:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <select>
        <option value="n136" selected>London</option>
        <option value="n240">Sydney</option>
        <option value="n179">New York City</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="n136 time">
    <iframe src="https://freesecure.timeanddate.com/clock/i50ppgou/n136/tluk/fcf90/tct/pct/ftb/bo2/pa10/th1" id="timeDisplay" frameborder="0" width="80" height="38" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select").change(function() {
        $("#timeDisplay")[0].src = "https://freesecure.timeanddate.com/clock/i50ppgou/" + $(this).attr("value") + "/tluk/fcf90/tct/pct/ftb/bo2/pa10/th1";
    }).change();
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p8ARq/610/

Comment: This is still inefficient as the op would still need to render 13 iframes and only show 1 based on user selection

Comment: Thank you this is much more efficient than what I had.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. The whole idea is to change the src attribute of the `iframe` tag based on appending the selected value from the dropdown.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('iframe').attr("src","https://freesecure.timeanddate.com/clock/i50ppgou/" + value + "/tluk/fcf90/tct/pct/ftb/bo2/pa10/th1")
    });     
});
```

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/p8ARq/612/

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

**==HTML==**

```
<div>
<select>
<option value="n136" selected>London</option>
<option value="n240" >Sydney</option>
<option value="n179">New York City</option>
</select>
</div>
<iframe id="AllTime" src="" frameborder="0" width="80" height="38" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

**==JS==**

```
 <script>  
    var f=$("iframe#AllTime"),s=$("select"), k=s.find("option:selected").val();
    //When Zone Change Do this
    s.change(function() {
         var n=$(this).val();   
         f.attr("src","https://freesecure.timeanddate.com/clock/i50ppgou/"+n+"/tluk/fcf90/tct/pct/ftb/bo2/pa10/th1");
       });
    //At first Do this
     f.attr("src","https://freesecure.timeanddate.com/clock/i50ppgou/"+k+"/tluk/fcf90/tct/pct/ftb/bo2/pa10/th1");
      </script>
```

**==Another JS Approach==**

```
<script> 
var f=$("iframe#AllTime"),s=$("select"), k=s.find("option:selected").val();
//When Zone Change Do this
function ChangeTimeZone(t){
f.attr("src","https://freesecure.timeanddate.com/clock/i50ppgou/"+t+"/tluk/fcf90/tct/pct/ftb/bo2/pa10/th1");    
}
//User change time zone
s.change(function() {
     var n=$(this).val();
      ChangeTimeZone(n);    
       });
//At first Do this
 ChangeTimeZone(k);
  </script>
```